# How to sum all values with different attribute name

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me to fix my problem. I had table like this :

```
<table id="initable" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-code="F01" data-price-max="1700000">
            <td>F01</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="sw-nml val-F01" name="content[0][nominal]" value="1.000" readonly="" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-code="F01" data-price-max="1700000">
            <td>F01</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="sw-nml val-F01" name="content[0][nominal]" value="2.000" readonly="" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-code="F02" data-price-max="1000000">
            <td>F02</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="sw-nml val-F02" name="content[0][nominal]" value="3.000" readonly="" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-code="F02" data-price-max="1000000">
            <td>F02</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="sw-nml val-F02" name="content[0][nominal]" value="8.000" readonly="" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-code="F01" data-price-max="1700000">
            <td>F01</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="sw-nml val-F01" name="content[0][nominal]" value="9.000" readonly="" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to sum all values according to the `data-code` attribute and if the sum results exceed the `data-price-max` it will display **"Price is too much"**.

And the result like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the reference

https://api.jquery.com/data/

combined with some math will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have many ways to accomplish this one if here.

The first is to know what is a data attribute and for what is your goal.

Here is a good explanation for store arbitrary data.
[data() function](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and here [data attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Then only you have to do is take the values and and a comparision of yours value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let totF01;
  let totF02;


  $('#initable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

    let maxprice = $(this).attr("data-price-max");
    let inputvalue = $(".val-" + $(this).attr("data-code")).val();
    if ($(this).attr("data-code") == "F01") {
      console.log("add to f01");
      totF01 = totF01 + inputvalue;
    } else if ($(this).attr("data-code") == "F02") {
      totF02 = totF02 + inputvalue;
    }



    if (inputvalue < maxprice) {
      console.log("Price is ok!");
    }else{
       console.log("Price is too much!");
    }

  });

  $("#totF01").html("$");//
  $("#totF02").html("$");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="initable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-code="F01" data-price-max="16660000">
      <td>F01</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="sw-nml val-F01" name="content[0][nominal]" value="17000" readonly="" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-code="F02" data-price-max="1700000">
      <td>F02</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="sw-nml val-F02" name="content[0][nominal]" value="27000" readonly="" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-code="F03" data-price-max="1000000">
      <td>F03</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="sw-nml val-F03" name="content[0][nominal]" value="37000" readonly="" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-code="F04" data-price-max="4000">
      <td>F04</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="sw-nml val-F04" name="content[0][nominal]" value="87000" readonly="" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-code="F05" data-price-max="17000">
      <td>F05</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="sw-nml val-F05" name="content[0][nominal]" value="97000" readonly="" style="width: 100px; text-align: right;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And then you can add easily add two tr on the footer of your table with result 
and make any operation.